# jQuery singling out time ranges from an array of time sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, time-series

I'm using jQuery to work with an array of one hour time sets such as:

```
{hours[0] = '12a-1a',
 hours[1] = '1a-2a',
 hours[2] = '2a-3a',
 hours[3] = '2p-3p',
 hours[4] = '9p-10p',
 hours[5] = '10p-11p'}
```

Wondering if anyone knows how to extract the beginning and ending time from a range of consecutive hours in the above array, such as:

range 1: 12a-3a

range 2: 2p-3p

range 3: 9p-11p

End goal is I would like to display the summarized ranges to the user like so:

You selected: 12a-3a and 2p-3p and 9p-11p

So far the only way I know how to display the user selection is to show each series from the hours array. On large sets this ends up being way too much to show on the screen.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: associative array - not sure on the correct format but I think people can understand the idea

Comment: This might be a XY problem. Maybe you should consider to use a data format that you can easily work with instead of those string representations.

Comment: If hours is an array you could just use `join` i.e.`hours.join(' and ')` ?

Comment: You need to convert the ranges to numeric values that can then be merged where they adjoin each other. Then you can apply the display formatting after merging.

Comment: Added working example of my suggestion below. It can be cleaned up more, but it should give you some ideas on how to approach this sort of problem... Pause for drum-roll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the data is in a custom string format, you need to do the following:

- Convert string times to time value entries
- Merge ranges of adjacent times
- Convert merged time ranges back to display format
- Display concatenated results using "and"

### Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bjjwwaq1/3/

```
var hours = [];
hours[0] = '12a-1a', hours[1] = '1a-2a', hours[2] = '2a-3a', hours[3] = '2p-3p', hours[4] = '9p-10p', hours[5] = '10p-11p';

// Convert a time like 1p-2p etc to an hour value pair
function convertToValue(hours) {
  // convert midnight to hour 0
  hours = hours.replace(/12a/, '0a');
  var parts = hours.split('-');
  var start = parseInt(parts[0]);
  if (parts[0].match(/p/)) {
    start += 12;
  }
  var end = parseInt(parts[1]);
  if (parts[1].match(/p/)) {
    end += 12;
  }
  return {
    start: start,
    end: end
  };
}

// Return a number in the range 0-23 as a string 12am, 11pm etc
function formatTime(time) {
  if (!time) {
    return "12a";
  } else if (time == 12) {
    return "12p";
  } else if (time > 12) {
    return (time - 12) + "p";
  }
  return time + "a";
}

// Convert an entry with start and end time to a formatted time like 1p-3p
function formattedTime(item) {
  return formatTime(item.start) + '-' + formatTime(item.end);
}

// Collect the converted results
var results = [];
$.each(hours, function(i, hours) {
  results.push(convertToValue(hours));
});

// Merge any adjacent times together
var merged = [];
$.each(results, function(i, result) {
  // If not first entry, see if this entry extends the previous entry
  if (i && result.start == results[i - 1].end) {
    // Extend the previous entry
    merged[merged.length - 1].end = result.end;
  } else {
    merged.push(result);
  }
});

// Save the new formatted output
var output = [];
$.each(merged, function(i, time) {
    output.push(formattedTime(time));
})

// Combine with "and" to get final result
console.log(output.join(" and "));
```

Which results in the output:

```
12a-2a and 2p-3p and 9p-10p
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!  All I had to do was edit: `function formattedTime(item) {
  return formatTime(item.start) + '-' + formatTime(item.end);
}` to `function formattedTime(item) {
  return formatTime(item.start) + '-' + formatTime(item.end + 1);
}` and it worked like a charm

Comment: You should not have needed to add 1 to the end times. Are you sure? I think the bug lays elsewhere... let me check

Comment: no once i changed it, it worked perfectly.  You are amazing!!!!  the desired output was `12a-3a and 2p-3p and 9p-11p`

Comment: No, the bug was in `merged[merged.length - 1].end = result.end;` go with my update (I accidentally had `= result.start`). If you use your fix it will only work for that one case (where last entry was 1 hour later).

Comment: I see....thanks for all the work on this one...if I could give you more rep I would!!!